# trouble getting specific value from while loop in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, swipe, attr

I am having trouble getting the specific id for a post when being outputted from a php while loop..
here is a loop I whipped up -

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $item  =$row['item'];
           echo '<li class="pane" data="'.$id.'">'.$item.'</li>'

    }
}
```

I then have a swipe function to initiate the call, I am using alerts for testing purposes and have quickly written the example to simply explain my problem..-

```
$("#tinderslide").jTinder({
    onDislike: function (item) {
        alert($('li').attr('data'));
    },
    onLike: function (item) {
     alert($('li').attr('data'));
    },
});
```

I have 3 items in the DB with id's 115, 116 and 117 but I can only get it to alert 117..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation of jTinder https://github.com/do-web/jTinder

> onDislike (Optional) - Default value: null - Callback function, if a user dislikes a item. Parameter assigned: The current li item.
>
> onLike (Optional) - Default value: null - Callback function if a user likes a item. Parameter assigned: The current li item.

You need write like this:

```
$("#tinderslide").jTinder({
    onDislike: function (item) {
        alert(item.attr('data'));
    },
    onLike: function (item) {
     alert(item.attr('data'));
    },
});
```

Comment: This worked perfect thank you! I was missing the item.attr.. instead of (this).attr

Answer (score 0):

If $('li') returns an array this is probably what you are after

```
 onLike: function (item) {
     alert($('li').each(function(){
           alert($(this).attr("data"));
     });
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I am getting the forEach is not a function error

Comment: Sorry yes you have to use JQuery each method. This should work now.

Comment: ya sorry I am having trouble still, getting the this.attr is not a function now

Comment: Ya it kind of works but fires the alert for every item in the DB, thanks for the try!